# UIScrollView breaks gesture recognizers in subviews

Tags: swift, autolayout, snapkit

What is the correct way to allow scrollview to pass gestures to the subviews?

Comment: I not sure what do you want. For the case your subview has a gesture conflict with its superview(scrollview), `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should add gesture recognizer to ScrollView like this:

```
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
        scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

Then handle the tap like this:

```
func handleTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer)  {

        let location = tap.locationInView(tap.view)

        for i in 0..<scrollView.subviews.count{
            let subViewTapped = scrollView.subviews[i]
            if CGRectContainsPoint(subViewTapped.frame, location) {

        print("tapped subview at index\(i)")
                // do your stuff here

            }
        }

    }
```